# Creating a function to sort two lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am attempting to create a function that returns a list of strings, sorted, but with the additional criteria that it sorts all of the strings that begin w/ `'x'` first.

So, for example, the list `['mix', 'xyz, 'apple', 'xanadu']` 
would yield `['xanadu', xyz', 'apple', 'mix']`

```
def front_x(words):
    x = []
    y = []
    for k, v in enumerate(words):
        if v.startswith("x"):
            x.append(v)
        else:
            y.append(v)

    x.sort()
    y.sort()
    print(x.extend(y))

this_list = ['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']

front_x(this_list)
```

This is giving me an output of `None`.

Comment: @TylerNCreed, why are you creating a function when you can use `sort` method or `sorted` function?

Comment: `front_x` does not return anything.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python sort lambda", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: It can be done with a lambda, and that seems to work just fine, but the current solution doesn't exactly use a function. Is there a way to do this without a lambda?

Comment: Reopening as the dupe is a different task involving a list filtering and *then* sorting, whereas here all strings must be included in the sorted list

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) with the following `key`:

```
l = ['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu']

sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[0]!='x', x))
# ['xanadu', 'xyz', 'apple', 'mix']
```

---

Or as @deepspace suggests using `str.startswith`:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda s: (not s.startswith('x'), s))
```

---

The above key is sorting the strings based on a tuple, consisting in a boolean resulting from the expression `x[0]!='x'`, and the string itself:

```
[(x[0]!='x', x) for x in l]
# [(True, 'mix'), (False, 'xyz'), (True, 'apple'), (False, 'xanadu')]
```

Hence the first criteria for sorting is whether or not the string begins with `x` (keep in mind that `False` and `True` are evaluated as `0` and `1`),  and then the string itself to sort alphanumerically.

Comment: I'd go with `sorted(l, key=lambda s: (not s.startswith('x'), s))` for sake of clear intent

Comment: That's a nice alternative @DeepSpace let me add it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sorted built-in function if you want to generate another list, but if you don't mind just changing the current list, use the method [list.sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

```py
>>> l = ['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu']
>>> l.sort(key=lambda s: (not s.startswith('x'), s))
>>> l
['xanadu', 'xyz', 'apple', 'mix']
```